# Javac: changing *.java does not change *.class

Tags: bash, javac

I am compiling and running some java code on a remote machine via ssh. I code on my laptop, commit to an svn repository, then update the remote working copy and re-compile the updated source files (both machines are running Linux). I've noticed that if I change a print statement in my code the output on the remote will not change. The source, however, is updated correctly. I suspect the problem is with my build script, which is pasted below:

```
cd $HOME/WindowsProfile/Desktop/torcs/versioned/anjiTest
export MYCLASSPATH=$HOME/WindowsProfile/Desktop/torcs/versioned/anjiTest/properties
for i in `ls $HOME/WindowsProfile/Desktop/torcs/versioned/anjiTest/lib/*.jar`
do
export MYCLASSPATH=${MYCLASSPATH}:${i}
done
MYCLASSPATH=${MYCLASSPATH}:$HOME/WindowsProfile/Desktop/torcs/versioned/anjiTest/build/classes
MYCLASSPATH=${MYCLASSPATH}:$HOME/WindowsProfile/Desktop/torcs/versioned/anjiTest/properties

echo $MYCLASSPATH

pwd
rm -R build/classes/*

javac -sourcepath ./src/ -classpath $MYCLASSPATH  ./src/A/*.java -d ./build/classes 
javac -sourcepath ./src/ -classpath $MYCLASSPATH  ./src/B/*.java -d ./build/classes 
javac -sourcepath ./src/ -classpath $MYCLASSPATH  ./src/C/*.java -d ./build/classes
```

My application relies on a large number of external libraries, which come as jar files- these are included in the classpath. I have physical access to the remote machine and I also noticed that if I build on it using NetBeans 6.9 the same problem occurs from time to time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The script above is fine.